# NodeJS as an instant messaging server for a MVP chat service

Tags: ios, node.js, architecture

I am working on a chat service with some unique features in it, and thinking about a server to dispatch messages and do all the IM-related stuff. First-priority client is going to be for iOS, built with Swift.

Is it feasible to create server, based on NodeJS Express, or may be [Loopback](http://loopback.io/)? I have had a look at multiple choices, including ready solutions, like [QuickBlox](http://quickblox.com/), Parse.

As for creating it from scratch, I think about NodeJS or Erlang.

At what stage should I make a decision so that not to waste too much time on reconfiguring everything for scaling and rapidity and convenience of development?

Comment: Worth looking - https://www.pubnub.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With technologies like Socket.io, Node.js, and Express, you could make a chat application fairly quickly.

Sockets are typically the best solution and the most common route to implementing a chat system, as they provide two way communication between the client and the server.

You could use practically any backend for a socket server, but it may end up being quicker to use Node.js and socket.io depending on your comfortability level with JavaScript.

All you would need is a socket compatible server and a client side library that connects to a socket server - there are plenty of JavaScript libs out there, including a socket.io-client.

Check out socket.io's chat demo on their site for a quick look at how it works:
http://socket.io/demos/chat/

They even provide a first party iOS Swift client:
https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift

Comment: +1. Agreed i've implemented a simple android chat with Socket.io, Node.js, and custom version of an android client available here https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-android-chat

Answer (score 1):

Personally I recommend you to checkout [SailsJS](http://sailsjs.org), a great framework for building API & chat server at the same time. It adopts socket.io internally so every route in a Sails app is compatible with socket.io (in other words, you can decide to call an API request via Socket anytime you wish!)

I've built a complete, working iOS App having chat feature. Its backend was completely developed using SailsJS. It saved me hundreds of hours. Sails documentation also mentions about scaling for production. Please have a look at http://sailsjs.org